# la115 lawnmower not crank

Tags: starting, lawnmower, john-deere

My john deere LA115 lawnmower wont crank when I turn the key lights come on only.It does not turn over at all but when I took the positive end to starter and grounded it turned over that way.What could it be?All it did was turning over but nothing when key is turned.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely one of the safety switches is not adjusted properly or is damaged.  There are three that will prevent the engine from starting:

1. The parking brake.  If the parking brake is not fully on, it will prevent the starter from turning over the engine.
2. The hydrostatic position.  If the "go" pedal on the right side of the mower is not in a neutral position, it will prevent the engine from turning over.
3. The seat pressure sensor.  If it doesn't sense enough weight in the seat,it will not start

Comment: There's more than likely a third safety switch, as in most riding lawn mowers, there's a pressure sensor in the seat. If you aren't sitting in the seat, it won't start, as well as if you try to get out of the seat when it's running (and safety items aren't set correctly) the mower will die. Agree with you, though, this seems like a safety switch issue.